# Loading Alert in SKPaymentTransaction

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I have been trying to create the subscription system and it's killing me.
I came now to this issue. So the user goes in and it takes some time till the alert from iTunes pops up. I decided to place the loading alert but I don't know when to stop it. I don't know where to place that method.

Here is my code:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .Purchasing:
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
                loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
                loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
                alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
                presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                break
            case .Purchased:
                self.validateReceipt()
                //self.setExpirationDate()
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                //dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                break
            case .Failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                print("Not called Expired")
                break
            case .Restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                print("Restored")
                break
            default:
                //dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)`
for closing of the loading alert.

Comment: you can stop indicator in "case .Purchased:", "case .Failed:", "case .Restored:"

Comment: It's not working if i place it there